# Retrieve the parameters when searchform action is post

Tags: php, wordpress

I do have a search form.

```
       <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl');?>">
         <div class="search_bx1"><input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'mclaren' ); ?>" /></div>
         <div class="search_btn1">
         <input type="image" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/search_btn.jpg" width="22" height="20" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>" />
        </div>
     </form>
```

I need to hide the image co-ordinates from the url.So i think i need to change the form method to post.But when i change the form action the redirection doesn't occur to search.php rather it goes to index.php.How can i overcome this.Please help?

I follow the default search method followed by the theme 'twentyeleven'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change the **`method`** attribute, not the `action`;

```
<form method="POST" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl');?>">
```

Comment: Hi,Sorry for the type error..i have updated it.The issue is when i change the method the redirect occurs to the home page, not to the default search.php.So i need to know which file to edit in WordPress to accommodate my needs.Or precisely i need to hide the image button co-ordinates shown on the URL.

Comment: Well, then appearantly the search.php only accepts GET parameters. You can also fix this by using a `<button>` instead of an `<input type="image">` in your form. Buttons can have images on them (or a `background-image` via CSS), and don't submit coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

A button and css would solve the issue..

```
      .search_btn1{
         background:url(images/search_btn.jpg) no-repeat;
          width:20px;
         height:20px;
          border: 0;
         cursor:pointer;
       }
```